# How to convert image in protobuf to bitmap in Android program

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

First, I called toByteString function, then, I called BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray function, but it didn't work, the bitmap was null

```
byte[] bytes  = response.getImage().getData().toByteArray();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: Are you sure the bytes represent a valid bitmap?  Protos aren't going to change the bytes at all; if they don't work when you get them out of the proto, then they don't work whether or not protos are involved.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.The camera takes the picture and sends it to the server, and then the server transmits the protobuf data format to the client